# Utilities.formatDate and timezone not working?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, date-formatting

I'm trying to output date with full words for day and month in French in a google spreadsheet script. (properties of spreadsheet and script has been set to (GMT+01:00) Paris)

```
var timezone = "Europe/Paris";
var date = new Date(2018,1,5,15,01,0,0);
var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(date, timezone, "EEEE d MMMM");
Logger.log(dateString);
```

Output is :

```
"Monday 5 February"
```

and when I try with a javascript function in the script :

```
dateString = date.toLocaleDateString("fr-FR", { weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" });
Logger.log(dateString);
```

Output is :

```
"5 February 2018"
```

And when I check in Safari console with the same function,

```
var date = new Date(2018,1,5,15,01,0,0);
date.toLocaleDateString("fr-FR", { weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" });
```

Output is :

```
"lundi 5 février 2018"
```

Code is good but it doesn't work for the script, I don't get it ...

Answer (score 0):

If your app needs to support more locales than English, you'll need to get Node to load the extra locale data, or use intl npm package to patch the runtime with the Intl polyfill. Node.js versions prior to 0.12 and ≥v3.1 don't provide the Intl APIs, so they require that the runtime is polyfilled.